# Is it possible to restrict Data Time Picker Dialog to only show time in Hour and Half an Hour?

Tags: java, android, datetimepicker

I am working on an application, where I have to show **time in hours** and **half an hour**, so my question is, is this possible to restrict the date time picker dialog to show only hours and half an hour time.

Comment: There are many more similar posts other than attached 2.

Comment: you can simply check  with minutes Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

if minutes egual to 00 or 30 then show picker else not.